# Rust macro that repeats with every combination of two lists?

Tags: rust, macros

I would like a Rust macro that, given two lists, repeats with every combination of items from those two lists. For example:

```
callback!(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]);
```

would generate:

```rust
callback('a', 1);
callback('a', 2);
callback('a', 3);
callback('b', 1);
callback('b', 2);
callback('b', 3);
callback('c', 1);
callback('c', 2);
callback('c', 3);
```

The [following macro](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=93488df632f62869af884aaed8fb3d39) should work, but fails at the second case. There seems to be something wrong with my repeated `$($zs,)*`. What is wrong with it?

```rust
macro_rules! m {
    (@a [$x:expr, $($xs:expr,)*] [$y:expr, $($ys:expr,)*] [$($zs:expr,)*]) => {
        println!("{} {}", $x, $y);
        m!(@a [$x, $($xs,)*] [$($ys,)*] [$($zs,)*]);
    };
    
    (@a [$x:expr, $($xs:expr,)*] [] [$($zs:expr,)*]) => {
        m!(@a [$($xs,)*] [$($zs,)*] [$($zs,)*]); // fails here
    };
    
    (@a [] [] [$($zs:expr,)*]) => {
        //done
    };
    
    ([$($xs:expr),*], [$($ys:expr),*]) => {
        m!(@a [$($xs,)*] [$($ys,)*] [$($ys,)*]);
    };
}

fn main() {
    m!(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]);
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like this can happen if the xlist is empty but the ylist is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this, just use a token tree that captures the whole second list as second argument, then you can trivially copy it for every element in the first list, and then repeat the call that for every element of that second list:

```rust
macro_rules! m {
    // only 1 element in first list
    // → just repeatedly call the callback for for every `$y`
    ([$x:expr], [$($y:expr),*]) => {
        $(println!("{}, {}", $x, $y);)*
    };
    // more than 1 element in first list
    // → call self with every `$x` as single first element.
    ([$($x:expr),*], $ys:tt) => {
        $(m!([$x], $ys);)*
    };
}
fn main() {
    callback!(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]);
}
```

prints:

```
a, 1
a, 2
a, 3
b, 1
b, 2
b, 3
c, 1
c, 2
c, 3
```